# Add +1 to p everytime the divis clicked

Tags: javascript, html, image

```
<div id="main">     

 <div id="rating">

  <div> <img src=""/>   <p>0</p>   </div>

 </div>

<div id="main">
```

I want to increment the number inside p everytime I click on the inner div. I've tried some methods. But they only work with buttons, and I don't want to change the HTML.

Comment: You can attach event handlers to arbitrary DOM elements with Javascript, not only to buttons. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener, which even has examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply bind a click event handler and update text inside the `p` tag on click.

```js
// add click event handler to the div
document.getElementById('rating').addEventListener('click', function() {
  // get p element inside the div
  var p = this.querySelector('p');
  // update the content
  p.textContent = Number(p.textContent) + 1;
});
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="rating">
    <div>
      <img src="" />
      <p>0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But the thing is that I can't add jquery.

Comment: It's working, thank you. Just one more question. What could I do if I want to do all this with (for example) 3 DIVs?

Comment: @yonige :  get all elements  using a class then iterate over them and bind the event handler